# Finding displacement using dampened oscillations (an attempt)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A cubical box of mass $10$ kg with edge length $5$ m is free to move on a frictionless horizontal surface. Inside is a small block of mass $2$ kg, which moves without friction inside the box. At time $t = 0$, the block is moving with velocity $5$ $\frac{m}{s}$ directly towards one of the faces of the box, while the box is initially at rest. The coefficient of restitution for any collision between the block and box is $90$%, meaning that the relative speed between the box and block immediately after a collision is $90$% of the relative speed between the box and block immediately before the collision.

After $1$ minute, the block is a displacement $x$ from the original position. Which of the following is closest to $x$?

[image]
There is a simple solution to the problem by using the velocity of the center of mass to calculate the displacement. However, I decided to take the hard way to solving the problem.
Let:

$m_c$ = mass of the cube

$m_b$ = mass of the block

$v$ = velocity of block @ $t=0$

First I attempted to establish a pattern to the velocity of the cube through repeated implementation of the conservation of linear momentum. I thus established a pattern of the velocity of the cube to be $$[\;1\,+\,(-1)^{n-1}(0.9)^{n}\;]\frac{m_bv}{m_c}$$ where $n$ is the number of collisions the block has with the cube as it is moving inside. I now want to model a dampening oscillator function that lies between the two "asymptotic functions" (shown in the graph) generated by the sequence and integrate that function with respect to the number of collisions ($n$) since $t(n) = \frac{5}{0.9^nv}$ can be used to find the time needed for the ($n+1$) collision to occur. The integral would be set up like:
$$\int_{n_1}^{n_2} v(n)\,dn$$
Then, I was thinking that I could differentiate both sides of the $t(n)$ function, giving us $dt = 0.10536 (0.9^{-n})\,dn$, and substitute $dn$ in the integral with $\frac{dt}{0.10536 (0.9^{-n})}$ and changing the bounds as necessary ($\int_{t_1}^{t_2}$)

I also need help finding the correct dampened oscillation equation ($v(n)$) that fits the graph below. That was my work so far and it probably doesn't make sense since this is the first time I'm doing this, but it would be appreciated if someone could proofread and/or help me solve this problem using a similar method with dampened oscillations (if that's possible) or with any other method besides using the center of mass.

[image]